# Update database via link

Tags: php, mysql

I am busy with an employee record project and would like to know if it is possible at all to have my project update the database via links?

Let me explain.

Within the editing of an employee I would like to add a menu with a couple of links. These links will only be used by our employers. The will (if the above mentioned is possible) be able to click on the link "dismissed", then that should update the database by means of changing the field "Employed_Status" to "0".

I could really use the help from professionals as I am still at the "Very beginner" stage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: learn AJAX , It will help you

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_GET` like

```
if(isset($_GET['status']) and $_GET['status']=='dismiss' and isset($_GET['empId']))
{
   $sql="Update employee SET Employed_Status=0
                WHERE Emp_id=".(int)$_GET['empId'];// if empid is integer
   // or use WHERE Emp_id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['empId']);
   // execute query $sql
}
```

**calling link** like, `http://example.com/page.php?empId=1&status=dismiss`

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and it's also using deprecated MySQL functions. If you want to keep using these functions, at least `mysql_real_escape_string` the `empId` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by transferring values from query string to tha page

```
<td><a href="insert.php?id=?"<?php echo (int) $_GET['id'] ?> >insert</a></td>
```

and on insert.php

extract this values using get method as:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

Also extract other values in similar manner and then fire your insert query with these values.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers and am sure all of them is correct. I have decided just to make the "employed_status" field editable so the users can change the settings there from a "1" to a "0".

thank you for your time.

Comment: Rohit, in your first line you should probably cast your `id` to an integer, otherwise that will allow the injection of malicious JavaScript in your page, allowing someone to steal a login cookie. So perhaps do something like `<?php echo (int) $_GET['id'] ?>`, assuming this is an integer. I'll undownvote if you would fix.

Comment: okey thaks for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Page:

```
<a href="action.php?val=0">Dismissed</a>

<a href="action.php?val=1">Activate</a>
```

action.php

```
$val=$_REQUEST['val'];

$sql = "UPDATE employee SET status = ? WHERE id = ?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($val,$empid));
```

Comment: `$val` is not escaped -> SQL Injection

Comment: Updated. Included PDO methods.